# Troubles using pyuic5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyuic

I had python 3.8.5 installed on my machine, and I have pyuic5 installed and used it to convert .ui to .py files (using cmd). I recently upgraded to python 3.8.7, and whenever I try to convert now, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\....>pyuic5 -x Windows.ui -o Windows.py
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\program files\python3.8.5\python.exe"  "D:\Program Files\Python 3.8.7\Scripts\pyuic5.exe" -x Windows.ui -o Windows.py': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I made sure that pyqt5 and pyuic5 have been installed correctly. I am no expert, but I believe that cmd is looking for the python.exe file from python3.8.5 folder (the older version I had installed) instead of the one in python3.8.7 folder.

Comment: use `pyuic5 -x /full/path/of/Windows.ui -o Windows.py`

Comment: I tried it already, and it unfortunately didn't work. The command mentioned in the question always used to work, but not after the upgrade anyways. You might have other ideas perhaps? Why is my cmd trying to look in "d:\program files\python3.8.5\python.exe and not 3.8.7?

Comment: @AhmedZeid Check your PATH envvar. Make sure it includes <new-python-dir>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5 (and also get rid of any old ones).

Comment: @ekhumoro, I did that, still the same error. Thing is "d:\program files\python3.8.5\python.exe" doesn't even exist on my computer. How to change that path?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I pip uninstalled/re-installed the following, and that solved my issue:
PyQt5
PyQt5-tools
PyQt5-sip
PyQtWebEngine

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had removed a previous Python version (3.8) and the program was ignoring the more recent one (3.10). The solution was to manually add a variable to **Windows path** with name **pyuic5** and the path to where the correct file is saved. I also removed the old variables pointing to Python 3.8.